# Is there a simple working Astrojs react Leaflet example?

Tags: reactjs, maps, openstreetmap, react-leaflet, astrojs

I like to have a simple working example with Astrojs and a React-Leaflet Map
i try to combine react leaflet examples from here

in component i added
SimpleMapWrapper.jsx

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer,Marker,Popup } from "react-leaflet";


const SimpleMapWrapper = () => {
    const position = [51.505, -0.09];
  return(
    <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={position}>
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  );
};
export default SimpleMapWrapper;
```

and in page i added
maptest.astro

```
---
import SimpleMapWrapper from "@components/map/simplemap.jsx"
---

<SimpleMapWrapper client:only="react"/>
```

tiles are not continously rendered

i found only one Example with react in Astro and react but looks complicated for me
https://github.com/ivanolmo/designo-site

and one  examples with Svelte https://rodneylab.com/astro-js-location-map/